# brightness filter is not working in live image GPUImage framework objective c

Tags: objective-c, gpuimagestillcamera

I'm working with camera live image filters using `GPUImage` framework, I've tried to perform the following part of code however it doesn't work.

```
GPUImageStillCamera*stillCamera=[[GPUImageStillCamera alloc]initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    stillCamera.outputImageOrientation=UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    outputView=[[GPUImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    bright=[[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc]init];

[bright setBrightness:self.slider_change.value];
[self.previewView addSubview:outputView];
bright.brightness=1.0;
   self.slider_change.minimumValue=-3.0;
   self.slider_change.maximumValue=3.0;
[stillCamera addTarget:bright];
[bright addTarget:outputView];
[bright useNextFrameForImageCapture];
[stillCamera startCameraCapture];
```

I would like to know what mistake I have done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're allocating your camera instance locally, and not holding on to a reference to it. Therefore, ARC will deallocate it as soon as your setup method exits. I explain this in the linked question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: I just tried in my app, when I move the slider it's very slow and the background becomes white color.I'm new bee for developing.

Comment: You're only allocating the camera and filters once, right? Make sure you're not creating a new camera or filter instance every time you move the slider. All you should need to do is set the brightness property on a change of the slider, nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply..I have created a AVCaptureSession for capturing the regular images and videos.For adding the filter I added your framework, but I coded [session stoprunning] in this method(were brightness filter added). I have remove the AVCaptureSession?

Comment: A GPUImageStillCamera creates its own AVCaptureSession and captures the images and video for you. You don't need to create another one, and if you do they may conflict with each other.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply.I'm so happy, you saved my day.

Comment: When I touch the slider for increasing or decreasing the brightness, my live image start to blink, I don't no what mistake I had done.

Comment: For this, you have to remove all the targets of the filter been used and add the brightness filter to your camera.Finally [camera startCameraCapture];